# Find a maximum in array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

I need to find the *max value* in `[[String:Any]]` array which looks like :

```
"date":someDate
"value":8
.
.

"date":anotherDate
"value":13
.
```

I need the max *value*(13), is there a simple way **without the traditional looping** over the array and extracting all numbers etc ?

Comment: Did you look at the `max(by:)` method of `Array`?

Comment: Yes, but it will find the max value in a single dictionary. I have an array of them and I need the max from all "values" keys from all dics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using `Array max(by:)`.

Note that this example uses a lot of crash operators (`!`). Safely unwrap as needed for your real code:

```
let data: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["date":Date(), "value":8],
    ["date":Data(), "value":13],
]

let maxEntry = data.max { ($0["value"] as! Int) < ($1["value"] as! Int) }!
let maxValue = maxEntry["value"] as! Int
```

Another option is to use `map` and `max`:

```
let maxValue = data.map { $0["value"] as! Int }.max()!
```

All these examples assume the array won't be empty and that each dictionary has a valid `Int` value for the `"value"` key. Adjust the code as needed if these assumptions are not valid.